# Мерж большой фичи с подстройкой под изменения master

Tags: git, контроль-версий, git-merge

Есть общая ветка `master` и долгоживущая большая ветка `feature`, которая сейчас готова и необходимо её слить с `master`. Во время разработки `feature` в `master`-е было принято решение изменить подход в именовании переменных, а в `feature` до сих пор содержатся переменные старого образца (как нетронутые, которые автосмержаться, так и новые для `feature`, но которые именовались по старой схеме, а также просто конфликтующие из-за изменений). Как лучше всего сделать мерж, чтобы изменить названия переменных, описать, почему они были изменены (ведь это не относится к ветке `feature` и имплементированной фиче, а именно к мержу), а также описать, почему так или иначе были разрешены возникшие конфликты? Надо делать отдельный коммит для резолва и переименования или можно обойтись одним? В результате хочется получить историю, в которой будет максимально понятно, почему были сделаны переименования и именно так разрешены конфликты, и не было нерабочих коммитов.

Переименования - просто пример, это могут быть любые изменения в `master`-е, которые не были сделаны в `feature`, в том числе такие, что просто смержить и потом исправить в `master`-е уже нельзя (например, критические баги).

Ещё желательно описать в мерже, что можно доделать в фиче в будущем. Нормально ли писать это в коммите? Если да, то в каком?

Comment: Делаете merge ветки `master` в `feature`, и еще один отдельный коммит, чтоб переименовать все новые переменные, а уже потом сливаете `feature` в `master`. Это в любом случае нужно делать, чтоб протестировать вашу ветку на предмет совместимости того, что там сделано с новыми изменениями в мастер.

Comment: @RomanKonoval тогда в истории будет 3 коммита для мержа, получается

Comment: Два, один из мастера в ветку, другой из ветки в мастер. Но они и так нужны, как я написал выше. Вы же не собираетесь сливать `feature` в мастер, не протестировав, что ваша ветка нормально работает с новыми изменениями в мастер? Это нужно сделать до того, как вы сделаете мерж в мастер, т.е. в вашей ветке.

Comment: @RomanKonoval почему не собираюсь? Я же могу в локальном мастере протестировать всё перед пушем. А 3 коммита это 2 мержа + 1 переименование

Comment: Так делать неудобно по многим причинам и обычно делают наоборот, стабилизируют свою ветку, а не master. Например, если после мержа в master у вас будет что-то не работать, то где будете исправлять ошибки? Если исправление займет время и кто-то уже что-то помержит в мастер, будете делать rebase или новый мерж и т.д.? Сливать изменения из мастера в feature-branch это нормальная и стандартная практика.

Comment: Если вы очень хотите чтоб история была без слитий, то делайте rebase своей ветки, т.е. перенос ее на самый новый комит в мастере. Тогда в вашей ветке будут все новые изменения из мастера. Дополнительно, вы можете сделать интерактивный rebase и интегрировать новый коммит(ы) с переименованиями в уже существующие коммиты (в те которые добавляли переменные), чтоб в истории все выглядело так, как если бы вы сразу делали правильные имена.

Comment: @RomanKonoval а вот это звучит неплохо. Я знаю, что можно сливать и разделять коммиты, переименовывать и игнорировать при ребейзе. А как "интегрировать новый коммит(ы) с переименованиями в уже существующие коммиты"?

Comment: @RomanKonoval и, если не сложно, ответьте, пожалуйста, на последний вопрос в вопросе

Comment: Что касается интеграции, то только вкратце, так как мало места, то даю ключевую инфу: интерактивный rebase, в нем изменение порядка комитов и команда fixup. Про последний вопрос не понял. Куда добавлять комментарии про возможные улучшения? Это зависит от того, кто будет читать. Как принято на проекте и т.д. Возможные места это: 1. commit description 2. PR/MR description 3. ticket в системе типа Jira 4. TODO прямо в коде. Что лучше это вы сами определите, кто и когда будет это читать? Куда он пойдет это искать и т.д. это уже от вашего проекта зависит